# Overlapping scatterplot, line through scatter plot and density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter, kernel-density

Is it possible to have overlapping density plots and the line through the scatter plot?

**Background**: I have data on which I make a regression model. I take the unique values of one of the variables in my data, and I see how the predictions vary across these unique values, and I plot these predictions. I would like the density of the original data, i.e. the density/histogram of the scatter plot of the unique values to lie in the background of my predicted line.

**To illustrate:**

```
library(dplyr)
iris2 = iris %>% mutate(pw_int=round(Petal.Width))
iris2_summary = iris2 %>% group_by(pw_int) %>% summarize(mean=mean(Sepal.Length))
```

So I pretend that the mean of Sepal.Length for each rounded value of Petal.Width is my model.

```
library(ggpubr)

ggscatterhist(
  iris, x = "Petal.Width", y = "Sepal.Length",
  #color = "Species", # comment out this and last line to remove the split by species
  #margin.plot = "histogram", density plots
  margin.params = list(color = "red", size = 0.2)
)
```

[image]

I would like to only have a histogram/density of the x-axis, but I don't know how.

**Attempt**:

```
lines(iris2_summary$pw_int,iris2_summary$mean,col="green",type="l")
```

does nothing for me. It seems that the following might be a method, but it looks really bad:

```
par(new=TRUE)

plot( iris2_summary$pw_int, iris2_summary$mean, type="l", col="green" )
```

There is also the issue that I don't know how to get the densities in the background.

[image]

**Desired output**:

[image]

Comment: If you'd like more flexibility, you'd need to not use pre-baked functions from `ggpubr` but rather `ggplot2` directly. The reason you're having issues with your attempt, is that you are trying to combine base plotting and ggplot, which is possible but not trivial.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I’m such a ggplot2-noob, rather a plotting noob in general :/